# Vanilla JS React Components in TypeScript files (ts, tsx)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I was just wondering if it is in any way possible to implement React class components the way they are implemented in Vanilla JS but in TypeScript application in .tsx files?

TypeScript compiler alerts me that **it failed to compile**  but how is that, that even though TypeScript is practically JavaScript and can compile plain JavaScript functions and many more stuff from JS, couldn't compile plain JavaScript components as it asks for implementing components properties and states interfaces to pass it to component?

The following code I provide results in compilation error in TypeScript application but not in plain JS:

```
export class Toggle extends React.Component {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isToggleOn: true };

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
        {this.state.isToggleOn ? "ON" : "OFF"}
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

Error message looks like this with underlined `.isToggleOn` in code:

```
TypeScript error in C:/.../Toggle.tsx(51,30)
Property 'isToggleOn' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}>'.  TS2339
```

Note that when I modify that first line to: `export class Toggle extends React.Component<{}, ToggleState>` and declare `ToggleState` interface, problem is solved.

Comment: please add the code that failed to compile and the error message

Comment: TS is not *exactly* "practically JavaScript". You can't compile JS as if TS *by default* unless you change some of the compiler options and weak the checks, because TS will expect a more strict typing and usage in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

Simple JavaScript does not care for the arguments to `Props` and `State`.
In TypeScript the compiler will not like it,so that where the error come from.
Without having a `ToggleState` explicity stated i'll suggest to provide a type for the state in the component's arguments.
this is my solution:

```
export class Toggle extends React.Component<{}, { isToggleOn: boolean }> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isToggleOn: true };

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
        {this.state.isToggleOn ? "ON" : "OFF"}
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

The best practice for maybe larger project is to separate the two, in order to have a more readable code.